# Woocommerce add to cart button positioning

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a WordPress theme for Woocommerce. So far so good, except for the "add to cart" button on the products (archive) page. I can modify the placement of the price and product title fine, but the add to cart element seems to be placed outside of the  wrapper the actual product tile is in. So, now the button creates extra space next to the actual tile it resides in. I already tried absolute positioning, but this becomes a nightmare in responsive design.

[image: the issue]

as you can see in the picture; I changed the "add to cart" text to a picture, but the result is the same when it was text-only. 
I've been digging through the Woocommerce php template files, but so far I can't find a way place the button inside of the  enclosure of the actual tile.

add-to-cart.php:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', // WPCS: XSS ok.
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
        isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product, $args );
```

css concerning the item:

```
a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(img/cart.svg);
    height: 32px;
    width: 37px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

In the end I'd like to move the cart button to right underneath the price.

Comment: It would be easier to see the problem if we can see the code or at least the page you are working on.

Comment: The only code is actually some css declaring the item as relative and the background image, the rest is handled by the woocommerce add-to-cart php files which I did not edit yet as I don't see what I need to edit for that. For good measure, I'll add the code of the "add-to-cart.php" to my main post, which seems to be controlling the specific link I'm talking about:

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. If you can send me the link, I can just play around with the code as a CSS hack could work.

Comment: The code from `add-to-cart.php` seems to output the link itself only - so if you wanted to change the position where the link is output in the HTML, you would have to go one level higher – and see where `add-to-cart.php` itself gets embedded/rendered.

Comment: @misorude how would I go about that? I'm fairly new to the world of web development.

Comment: Check the template(s) for the product archive pages, see where it gets output there … Or search for the file name across the whole code base in your IDE.